# Earth's inner core has an inner core inside itself. Are there three inner cores?

Tags: geology, seismology, core

The Seeker.com article [Earth's Inner Core Has Its Own Inner Core](https://www.seeker.com/earths-inner-core-has-its-own-inner-core-1769514804.html) states that

> researchers at University of Illinois and Nanjing University in China have made a bizarre discovery. They've found that the Earth's inner core has an inner core of its own, like a Russian nesting doll, that has different properties from what scientists have previously imagined

Is it possible that there could be three cores?

Comment: Is it possible?   Absolutely.   There's a lot we don't know about Earth's core.  There might be a 4th layer, quite small, made up of Platinum, Gold and other dense metals.     http://discovermagazine.com/2006/sep/innerfortknox

Comment: Cool! I guess it makes perfect sense for earth to have more then two or three cores/layers. Thanks